# PDFMAKE: 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' not found in virtual file system ONLY AFTER GULP

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, gulp, require, pdfmake

I created a simple app using knockout/bootstrap/gulp that downloads a pdf using pdfMake.js. It works fine in debug mode using VS2017. After publishing and using gulp it gives this error when run: **File 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' not found in virtual file system**

**Note: After gulp, all JS files are in one script.js file.**

I tried many things, it always works when debugging, as soon as I run gulp, it gives the error.

I tried joepal1976's solution from [here](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/302) (what I did with the dependencies in require.config.js)

Someone suggested .pipe(uglify({
                    compress: {
                       hoist_funs: false
                    }
                 })) which doesn't appear to help.

**Included in require.config like so:**

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: ".",
    paths: {
        "jquery":               "js-libs/jquery.min",
        "bootstrap":            "js-libs/bootstrap.min",
        "crossroads":           "js-libs/crossroads.min",
        "hasher":               "js-libs/hasher.min",
        "knockout":             "js-libs/knockout",
        "knockout-projections": "js-libs/knockout-projections.min",
        "signals":              "js-libs/signals.min",
        "text":                 "js-libs/text",
        "vfs_fonts":            "js-libs/vfs_fonts",
        "pdfMake":              "js-libs/pdfmake.min"
    },
    shim: {
        "bootstrap": { deps: ["jquery"] },
        'pdfMake':
        {
            exports: 'vfs_fonts'
        },
        'vfs_fonts':
        {
            deps: ['pdfMake'],
            exports: 'vfs_fonts'
        }
    }
};
```

**JS for the page:**

```
define(["knockout", "text!./home.html"], function (ko, homeTemplate) {
function HomeViewModel(route) {
    var thisVM = this;


    this.VMInit = function () {

        var thePDF = {
            content: [
                'My test invoice.',
            ]
        };

        pdfMake.createPdf(thePDF).download('pdf_test.pdf');

    }

    thisVM.VMInit();
}
return { viewModel: HomeViewModel, template: homeTemplate };

});
```

**The Gulp file:**

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Node modules
var fs      = require('fs'),
vm      = require('vm'),
merge   = require('deeply'),
chalk   = require('chalk'),
es      = require('event-stream');

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Gulp and plugins
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
rjs         = require('gulp-requirejs-bundler'),
concat      = require('gulp-concat'),
clean       = require('gulp-clean'),
replace     = require('gulp-replace'),
uglify      = require('gulp-uglify'),
htmlreplace = require('gulp-html-replace');

// Config
var requireJsRuntimeConfig = 
vm.runInNewContext(fs.readFileSync('src/app/require.config.js') + '; require;');
requireJsOptimizerConfig = merge(requireJsRuntimeConfig, {
    out: 'scripts.js',
    baseUrl: './src',
    name: 'app/startup',
    paths: {
        requireLib: 'js-libs/require'
    },
    include: [
        'requireLib',
        'components/nav-bar/nav-bar',
        'components/home-page/home',
        'text!components/about-page/about.html'
    ],
    insertRequire: ['app/startup'],
    bundles: {
        // If you want parts of the site to load on demand, remove them from the 'include' list
        // above, and group them into bundles here.
        // 'bundle-name': [ 'some/module', 'another/module' ],
        // 'another-bundle-name': [ 'yet-another-module' ]
    }
});

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Discovers all AMD dependencies, concatenates together all required .js 
files, minifies them
gulp.task('js', function () {
    return rjs(requireJsOptimizerConfig)
        .pipe(replace('Views/src/', ''))
        .pipe(replace('img/', 'Assets/img/'))
        .pipe(replace('css/', 'Assets/css/'))
        .pipe(uglify({
            preserveComments: 'some'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist-app/Assets/js/'));
});


gulp.task('css', function () {
return gulp.src(['./src/css/bootstrap.css',
                 './src/css/bootstrap-switch.css',
                 './src/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css',
                 './src/css/dataTables.colVis.css',
                 './src/css/dataTables.responsive.css',
                 './src/css/daterangePicker.css'])
    .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist-app/Assets/css/'));
});


// Copies index.html, replacing <script> and <link> tags to reference production 
URLs
gulp.task('html', function () {
return gulp.src('./src/index.html')
    .pipe(htmlreplace({
        dependencies_top: '<link href="Assets/css/styles.css" 
rel="stylesheet">',
        dependencies_bottom: '<script src="Assets/js/scripts.js"></script>'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist-app/'));
});



// Removes all files from ./dist/
gulp.task('clean', function () {
console.log("the clean task");
return gulp.src('./dist-app/**/*', { read: false })
    .pipe(clean());
});

// All tasks in [] must complete before 'default' can begin
gulp.task('default', ['html', 'js', 'css'], function (callback) {
callback();
console.log('\nPlaced optimized files in ' + chalk.magenta('dist-app/\n'));
});
```

**The Startup.js file if its helpful:**

```
define(['jquery',
    'knockout',
    './router',
    'bootstrap',
    'knockout-projections',
    'pdfMake',
    'vfs_fonts'], function ($, ko, router) {

// Components can be packaged as AMD modules, such as the following:
ko.components.register('nav-bar', { require: 'components/nav-bar/nav-bar' });
ko.components.register('home-page', { require: 'components/home-page/home' 
});

// ... or for template-only components, you can just point to a .html file 
directly:
ko.components.register('about-page', {
template: { require: 'text!components/about-page/about.html' }
});

ko.components.register('new-page', { require: 'components/new-page/new-page' 
});

// [Scaffolded component registrations will be inserted here. To retain this 
//feature, don't remove this comment.]

// Start the application
ko.applyBindings({ route: router.currentRoute });
});
```

Answer (score 54):

Following code worked for me:

```
import pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import pdfFonts from "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts";
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

Comment: Thx! Saved me to make work on Rails 6 + Webpacker.

Comment: Also works on Symfony 5 and webpack

Answer (score 17):

I battled with this recently on stackblitz when using it with angular. the issue was pdfmake.vfs on the window object was not being set. so i had to manually set it in the constructor of my pdf service like so.

```
  constructor() {
    (window as any).pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
  }
```

Comment: You can try something like this I'm using in my main.js webpack file:

    var pdfMake = require('pdfmake');
    var pdfFonts = require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js');
    pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
    window.pdfMake = pdfMake;

Answer (score 15):

I came across this issue and resolved it by including `vfs_fonts.js` just after the pdfmake Javascript file.

Here is my code, you should just need to set the file path to wherever your copy of the file is placed.

```
<script src="~/Content/DataTables/pdfmake-0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/DataTables/pdfmake-0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
```

#### CDN LINK

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
```

please follow the hierarchy/dependency of links else it won't work

Comment: After the gulp, all JS files are in one script.js file. It works fine before the gulp, all the files are referenced correctly for it to work before that.

Answer (score 4):

It is just the sequence of the files, add **first** the **pdfmake** and **then** **vfs_fonts**.

Comment: That is so odd. But it does, in fact, fix the problem instantly.

Comment: Never mind, not that odd. I looked at the first line of code. The fonts are not as general purpose as I expected: pdfmake objects are used to load the fonts, so it makes sense that the core library needs to be initialized first.

Answer (score 1):

@Rijo solution worked in one file, but oddly enough refused to work in another file.

In the other file I had to use:

```js
import pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import pdfFonts from "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts";

// Wherever you call createPdf, you have to pass VFS
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition, null, null, pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs).open();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this fonts script in ReactJs:**

```
import pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min";

pdfMake.fonts = {
    Roboto: {
      normal: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
      bold: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf',
      italics: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
      bolditalics: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.66/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'
    }
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).